# Sub Procedure Data not showing in listbox

Tags: vb.net

EDIT: So I have managed to get the GetData Function to appear in the list but not the ComputeBalance entry. I can't figure out what I have done wrong. I am unsure how to get the data from those calculations to appear in the listbox.

```
'Get Users Data via Textbox Input'
Private Sub GetData(ByRef parCreditCard As String, ByRef parBalance As Double, ByRef parPurchases As Double, ByRef parPayment As Double)

    parCreditCard = txtCreditCard.Text
    parBalance = txtBalance.Text
    parPurchases = txtPurchases.Text
    parPayment = txtPayment.Text

End Sub
'Compute Balance'
Private Sub ComputeBalance(ByVal parBalance, ByVal parPurchases, ByVal parPayment)
    Dim financeCharge, endBalance, minPayment As Double


    financeCharge = parBalance * 0.015
    endBalance = ((financeCharge) + (parBalance) + (parPurchases)) - (parPayment)

    If parBalance <= 10 Then
        minPayment = endBalance
    Else
        minPayment = (endBalance * 0.05)
    End If
End Sub
'Display Items to list'
Private Sub DisplayStatement(ByVal parCreditCard, ByVal parBalance, ByVal parPurchases, ByVal parPayment, ByVal financeCharge, ByVal endBalance, ByVal minPayment)
    lstStatement.Items.Clear()
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Credit Card Number:" & vbTab & parCreditCard & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Beginning Balance:" & vbTab & parBalance & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Total Purchases:" & vbTab & parPurchases & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Total Payments:" & vbTab & parPayment & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Finance Charges:" & vbTab & financeCharge & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("End of Month Balance:" & vbTab & endBalance & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Minimum Payment:" & vbTab & minPayment & vbTab)

End Sub
Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment, financeCharge, endBalance, minPayment As Double
    Dim parCreditCard As String
    GetData(parCreditCard, parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment)
    ComputeBalance(endBalance, minPayment, financeCharge)
    DisplayStatement(parCreditCard, parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment, financeCharge, endBalance, minPayment)

End Sub

Private Sub txtCreditCardNumber_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCreditCard.TextChanged

End Sub

Private Sub txtFirstBalance_TextChanged(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBalance.TextChanged

End Sub
End Class
```

Edit 2: Well I managed to get it to work, but I am sure the way I did it can be done in a simpler way, nevertheless here is the code I used:

```
 Public Class Lab4
 'Get Users Data via Textbox Input'
Public Sub GetData(ByRef parCreditCard As String, ByRef parBalance As Double, ByRef parPurchases As Double, ByRef parPayment As Double)
    parCreditCard = txtCreditCard.Text
    parBalance = txtBalance.Text
    parPurchases = txtPurchases.Text
    parPayment = txtPayment.Text

End Sub

'Compute Balance'
Private Sub ComputeBalance(ByRef parBalance As Double, ByRef parPurchases As Double, ByRef parPayment As Double)
    Dim financeCharge, endBalance, minPayment As String
    parBalance = txtBalance.Text
    parPayment = txtPayment.Text
    parPurchases = txtPurchases.Text
    financeCharge = parBalance * 0.015
    endBalance = ((financeCharge) + (parBalance) + (parPurchases)) - (parPayment)
    If parBalance <= 10 Then
        minPayment = endBalance
    Else
        minPayment = (endBalance * 0.05)
    End If
    txtFinance.Text = financeCharge
    txtEndBalance.Text = endBalance
    txtMinPayment.Text = minPayment
End Sub

'Display Items to list'
Private Sub DisplayStatement(ByVal parCreditCard, ByVal parBalance, ByVal parPurchases, ByVal parPayment, ByVal financeCharge, ByVal endBalance, ByVal minPayment)
    financeCharge = txtFinance.Text
    endBalance = txtEndBalance.Text
    minPayment = txtMinPayment.Text
    lstStatement.Items.Clear()
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Credit Card Number:" & vbTab & parCreditCard & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Beginning Balance:" & vbTab & parBalance & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Total Purchases:" & vbTab & parPurchases & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Total Payments:" & vbTab & parPayment & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Finance Charges:" & vbTab & financeCharge & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Month End Balance:" & vbTab & endBalance & vbTab)
    lstStatement.Items.Add("Minimum Payment:" & vbTab & minPayment & vbTab)
End Sub

Private Sub btnCalculate_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnCalculate.Click
    Dim parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment, financeCharge, endBalance, minPayment As Double
    Dim parCreditCard As String
    GetData(parCreditCard, parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment)
    ComputeBalance(parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment)
    DisplayStatement(parCreditCard, parBalance, parPurchases, parPayment, financeCharge, endBalance, minPayment)
End Sub

Private Sub txtCreditCardNumber_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtCreditCard.TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub txtFirstBalance_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles txtBalance.TextChanged
End Sub

Private Sub lstStatement_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles lstStatement.SelectedIndexChanged

End Sub

Private Sub Lab4_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is VB.NET, not VB6.

Answer (score 0):

First, `financeCharge`, `endBalance`, and `minPayment` are declared as local variables to `Sub ComputeBalance`. Second, you actually declared a different set of variables named `financeCharge`, `endBalance`, and `minPayment` as local variables in `Sub btnCalculate_Click`. You probably meant to declare variables (at the module level) for the whole Form.

Comment: So how could I fix it so that those items will display in the listbox?